# How change task priority in cloudsim?

Tags: cloudsim

I change task priorities based my algorithm now I want gives this tasks to vms , How I can do it in cloudsim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the 'classType' parameter of cloudLet object from your algorithm to priorotize them.

Comment: Despite there is the `classType` attribute, it isn't used anywhere in CloudSim. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571651/what-kind-of-criteria-can-be-design-to-give-priorties-to-cloudlet-in-cloudsim/53669205#53669205) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method `bindCloudletToVm` of the `class DatacenterBroker`. You can refer [this](http://www.cloudbus.org/cloudsim/doc/api/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/DatacenterBroker.html)